# SQL Help - Newbie

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I'm picking up the pieces for a friend. His website used to work and pull featured products from his database, but it doesn't seem to be working. Its just showing the Error!!

Any help would be appreciated.... I'm not really up to date with SQL.

Here's the code:

```
<?php
require_once('const.php');
$link = dbConnect();

$query = "SELECT *
          FROM vehicle_tbl, manufacturer_tbl
          LEFT JOIN image_tbl ON vehicle_tbl.vehicle_id = image_tbl.vehicle_id  
          WHERE vehicle_tbl.manufacturer_id = manufacturer_tbl.manufacturer_id AND
                vehicle_tbl.vehicle_feature2 = '1' 
          GROUP BY vehicle_tbl.vehicle_id
          ORDER BY RAND()
          LIMIT 1";

$result = false;
$result = @mysql_query($query, $link);
$fmain = false;
if (($result) && (@mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)) {
    $fmain = @mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
    @mysql_free_result($result);
}

$query = "SELECT *
          FROM vehicle_tbl, manufacturer_tbl
          LEFT JOIN image_tbl ON vehicle_tbl.vehicle_id = image_tbl.vehicle_id  
          WHERE vehicle_tbl.manufacturer_id = manufacturer_tbl.manufacturer_id AND
                vehicle_tbl.vehicle_feature1 = '1' 
          GROUP BY vehicle_tbl.vehicle_id
          ORDER BY RAND()
          LIMIT 6";

$offers = false;
$offers = @mysql_query($query, $link);

function nextOffer() {
    global $offers;
    if ($offers && ($row = mysql_fetch_array($offers))) {
        if (! isset($row['image_name'])) { // no image
            $image = 'images/noimagesml.jpg';
        } else {
            $image = 'images/vehicles/sml/'.stripslashes($row['image_name']);
        }
        $title = stripslashes($row['manufacturer_name']).' '.stripslashes($row['vehicle_model']);
        $price = number_format((float) $row['vehicle_price_pcm'], 2);
        $id = (int) $row['vehicle_id'];
        echo '<table width="100%"  border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                          <tr>
                            <td class="contenthead"><table width="100%"  border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                              <tr>
                                <td width="11" height="40" align="left" valign="top"><img src="images/featre_left_hd.gif" width="11" height="23"></td>
                                <td width="100%" align="left" valign="middle" class="contenthead">'.$title.'</td>
                                <td width="11" height="40" align="right" valign="top"><img src="images/featre_rght_hd.gif" width="11" height="23"></td>
                              </tr>
                            </table></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td class="contentpane"><table width="100%"  border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="0">
                              <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="middle"><img src="'.$image.'" width="100" height="58" class="bordered" alt="'.$title.'"></td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top" class="princing">from just &pound'.$price.' pcm</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td align="right" valign="middle"><a href="cardeal.php?vehicle='.$id.'"><img src="images/more_butt.gif" width="54" height="20" border="0"></a></td>
                              </tr>
                            </table></td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>';
    } else {
        echo 'Error!!';
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Maybe he means shows **Error!!** (see last line of PHP)

Comment: the big trouble are the '@'

Comment: Because you're suppressing all the errors using `@` you can't see actual errors. Try removing `@`s and start debugging.

Comment: Sorry i did mean the last line of the php Error!! Ive removed all the @'s but still getting the same response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Display mysql errors like this:

```
mysql_query($query, $link) or die(__FILE__ . ' Line ' . __LINE__ . ': ' . mysql_error());
```

This should help you debug.

P.S. the mysql_* functions are deprecated - http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Comment: I think it is to do with the depreceated functions... im really a newbie on this and not sure which or what i need to change it too... Any help would be great though!

Comment: Replace wherever you currently have `@mysql_query($query, $link);` in your example code with `mysql_query($query, $link) or die(__FILE__ . ' Line ' . __LINE__ . ': ' . mysql_error());`, and try refreshing the page. What does that give you? Tell us the entire error message displayed.

Comment: Hi Josh right ive replaced everything like you said I now get:

/home/wwwtyres/public_html/new/index1.php Line 12: Unknown column 'vehicle_tbl.vehicle_id' in 'on clause'

Comment: This is the kind of debug information that really helps. Does the field `vehicle_id` actually exist in the table `vehicle_tbl`? Double check the spelling of it too.

Comment: vehicle_id 100% exists in vehicle_tbl and has data in it too.

Comment: Curious. Does naming the tables like this help? 
`SELECT *
          FROM vehicle_tbl AS v, manufacturer_tbl AS m
          LEFT JOIN image_tbl AS i ON v.vehicle_id = i.vehicle_id  
          WHERE v.manufacturer_id = m.manufacturer_id AND
                v.vehicle_feature2 = '1' 
          GROUP BY v.vehicle_id
          ORDER BY RAND()
          LIMIT 1`

Comment: I changed the top query to: 

$query = "SELECT * FROM vehicle_tbl AS v, manufacturer_tbl AS m LEFT
    JOIN image_tbl AS i ON vehicle_id = i.vehicle_id
       WHERE v.manufacturer_id = m.manufacturer_id
    AND v.vehicle_feature2 = '1'
    GROUP BY v.vehicle_id ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";

and it displays ok.... I now just need to amend the bottom query...

Comment: All sorted! $query = "SELECT * FROM vehicle_tbl AS v, manufacturer_tbl AS m LEFT
    JOIN image_tbl  AS i ON vehicle_id = i.vehicle_id  
    WHERE v.manufacturer_id = m.manufacturer_id
    AND v.vehicle_feature1 = '1' 
    GROUP BY v.vehicle_id ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 6";

Comment: Just 1 issue, it doesn't seem to link the $id from the vehicle_id 

$id = (int) $row['vehicle_id'];

<a href="cardeal.php?vehicle='.$id.'">

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146041/php-mysql-how-to-get-ambiguous-column-result-from-joined-table

- you need to alias the ambiguous field, like you just did with the tables. Change your select statements to something like this: `SELECT *, vehicle_tbl.vehicle_id AS vehicle_id_alias LEFT JOIN...etc` then reference the field `vehicle_id_alias` in your php. This clears up any ambiguity.

Comment: Sorry for being such a newbie! Ive tried numerous times today but still cant work it out what needs changing:

$query = "SELECT * FROM vehicle_tbl AS v, manufacturer_tbl AS m LEFT
    JOIN image_tbl AS i ON vehicle_id = i.vehicle_id
       WHERE v.manufacturer_id = m.manufacturer_id
    AND v.vehicle_feature2 = '1'
    GROUP BY v.vehicle_id ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";

Comment: Try this: `$query = "SELECT *, v.vehicle_id AS vehicle_id_alias FROM vehicle_tbl AS v, manufacturer_tbl AS m LEFT JOIN image_tbl AS i ON v.vehicle_id = i.vehicle_id WHERE v.manufacturer_id = m.manufacturer_id AND v.vehicle_feature2 = '1' GROUP BY v.vehicle_id ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";` - you missed a `v.` or `m.` in your `ON` clause. I've assumed `v.vehicle_id` above. Then reference `$row['vehicle_id_alias']` in your PHP.

Comment: If I use the query you posted above I get:

Line 11: Unknown column 'v.vehicle_id' in 'on clause'

Comment: If I use the query you posted above I get:
*Line 11: Unknown column 'v.vehicle_id' in 'on clause'*I swapped *LEFT JOIN image_tbl AS i ON v.vehicle_id = i.vehicle_id* for *LEFT JOIN image_tbl AS i ON vehicle_id = i.vehicle_id* and it works however I need to sort out my search.php page now

Comment: This is my search.php `code` $query = "SELECT manufacturer_name FROM manufacturer_tbl WHERE manufacturer_id = $manufacturer_id";
$result = false;
$result = mysql_query($query, $link) or die(__FILE__ . ' Line ' . __LINE__ . ': ' . mysql_error());
if (($result) && (@mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)) {
 $row = @mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
 $name = stripslashes($row['manufacturer_name']);
}$query = "SELECT * FROM vehicle_tbl LEFT JOIN image_tbl ON vehicle_tbl.vehicle_id = image_tbl.vehicle_id 
    WHERE vehicle_tbl.manufacturer_id = $manufacturer_id GROUP BY vehicle_tbl.vehicle_id";`code`

Comment: That's a different question really... you'll need to ask another and accept this answer if it helped you.

Comment: No worries 1 issue I still have with my existing index.php page though is that it's not pulling the correct image for each result through stil. You have been a great help too btw.

Comment: No its showing 1 image for all results.  Looks like its picked the first image from the database. **http://www.tyresinwigan.co.uk/new/index.php**

Comment: Then that's definitely a different problem - please ask it as a new question and accept this answer if it helped you.